# Compatibility Issues between Tableau 10.3 and Cloudera Hive 2.0

Tags: hive, tableau-api, cloudera

We are upgrading Our Cloudera Hive from 1.3 to 2.0, Could you please let us know, if there is known issues related to this, i did a search in Tableau and Cloudera Community, but i didn't found any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something on the [Known Issues page](https://www.tableau.com/support/known-issues) then in general there should be no problems.

If you are concerned, then I would strongly suggest upgrading a test database instance from 1.3 to 2.0, and then confirming your exact 10.3 version of Tableau can connect to this new version without any issues. If any issues are experienced, then please contact Tableau Technical Support and they will assist you with next steps.